# how to count clicks on an element other than a button?

Tags: javascript

I have an empty box in the footer section, which is situated in the div

```
<footer>
<div>
</div>
</footer>
```

I would like to write a function in javascript that would count the number of clicks in the div, and display the number of clicks in the same div. I am wondering how to achieve this without touching the html. I have seen how to achieve this with a button, but how can I achieve this with a div ? thanks

Comment: The same way as you would do it for a button. Just add the click event listener to the div.

Comment: you have to learn about events in js

Comment: If the div is empty, how will they click on it?

Comment: The button is nothing but a div with some event embedded into it

Comment: but im not allowed to touch modify the div

Comment: Please share the code you used for the button - it's likely to be quite similar. In short, you can attach event handlers to click events of any element type, and in that event handler function you can update the inner html of some div. (1) select an element. (2) attach event listener with a function. (3) in that function select an element and update it

Comment: Why would you need to modify the div?

Comment: Do you know how to use `addEventListener()`?

Comment: I don't know how to add an onclick on something else than a button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **.querySelector**, if you dont to want add any ID or Class.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('footer div');

let countClicks = 0;

elem.onclick = function() { 
  countClicks++;
  elem.textContent = countClicks
};
```

```css
div {
padding:10px;
background: #339900; 
color: #fff;
font-size: 44px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');

root.onclick = function() { 
var elem = document.getElementById('count');
  elem.innerHTML = +elem.innerText + 1;
};
```

```css
#count {
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="root">Click HERE</div>
  <div id="count"></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('footer > div');

div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const previousValue = Number.parseInt(div.innerText || 0);
  div.innerText = previousValue + 1;
});
```

```css
footer div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div>
</div>
</footer>
```